# Drupal 7, how to dynamically populate a field based on the summation of two other fields?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-forms, drupal-ajax

I have two fields

```
$form["field_num_males"]
$form["field_num_females"]
```

I need to dynamically populate the field $form["field_gender_total"] with the summation of them, before the submission (AJAX).

How can this be done with Drupal 7?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it can be done with Ajax. The following code will automatic update the total when the text field is updated:

```
function gender_total_menu()
{
    $items = array();

    $items['test'] = array(
        'title'           => Gender total,
        'page callback'   => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments'  => array('gender_total_form'),
        'access callback' => array(TRUE),
        'type'            => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );

    return $items;
}

function gender_total_form($form, &$form_state)
{
    $total = 0;

    if (array_key_exists('values', $form_state) &&
        array_key_exists('field_num_males', $form_state['values']) &&
        array_key_exists('field_num_females', $form_state['values'])
    ) {
        $total = $form_state['values']['field_num_males'] + $form_state['values']['field_num_females'];
    }

    $form = array();

    $form["field_num_males"] = array(
        '#type'          => 'textfield',
        '#title'         => t("Number of males"),
        '#default_value' => 0,
        '#ajax' => array(
            'callback' => 'ajax_update_callback',
            'wrapper'  => 'wrapper',
        ),
    );

    $form["field_num_females"] = array(
        '#type'          => 'textfield',
        '#title'         => t("Number of females"),
        '#default_value' => 0,
        '#ajax' => array(
            'callback' => 'ajax_update_callback',
            'wrapper'  => 'wrapper',
        ),
    );

    $form['total'] = array(
        '#markup' => '<p> Total: ' . $total . '</p>',
        '#prefix' => '<div id="wrapper">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
    );

    return $form;
}

function ajax_update_callback($form, $form_state)
{
    return $form['total'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Computed Field](http://drupal.org/project/computed_field) module

> Computed Field is a very powerful CCK field module that lets you add a
>   custom "computed fields" to your content types. These computed fields
>   are populated with values that you define via PHP code. You may draw
>   on anything available to Drupal, including other fields...

Comment: Does it populate the fields on the fly while filling the form? I think the computed field is hidden, and save in the database....